# Iterating and Applying Regex functions/str counts over multple columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am new to python and trying to improve on this test df. I was able to apply a regex function to find a pattern in a cell and then provide me the count of how many 1's there are on a individual column level. Below is an image of the original and resultant df from applying the function individually to columns, and the codes for the individual columns. Below is also the text version of the test df (missing one row from image to make it sharing easier / image won't match test df but similar results):

```
import pandas as pd
        
df = pd.DataFrame([["1 | | Had a Greeter welcome clients 1     | | Take measures to ensure a safe and organized distribution 1         | | Protected confidentiality of clients (on social media, pictures, in conversation, own congregation members receiving assistance, etc.)",
                    "1  | | Chairs for clients to sit in while waiting 1     | | Take measures to ensure a safe and organized distribution"],
                   ["1 | Financial literacy/budgeting 1 | | Monetary/Bill Support 1    | | Mental Health Services/Counseling",
                    "1| | Clothing Assistance 1  | | Healthcare 1    | | Mental Health Services/Counseling 1     | | Spiritual Support 1      | | Job Skills Training"]
                    ] , columns = ['CF1', 'CF2'])
```

[image: Original Pattern]

[image: Resultant DF]

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+') 
df['CF1test'] = df['CF1'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(pattern.findall(x))).str.count(pattern) 
df['CF2test'] = df['CF2'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(pattern.findall(x))).str.count(pattern)
```

Here is a sample for loop I was trying to develop to iterate and apply that same function to multiple columns:

```
for column in df:
    df[column] = df.join([column](df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(pattern.findall(x))).str.count(pattern), rsuffix = '_test'))
```

However, I am getting 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' and I am lost. Is there a better method available? Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: please provide your input data as **text**

Comment: Hi @mozay. The input data for the loop is the same from the first image. I am trying to loop through multiple columns that are structured similar to CF1 & CF2 (i.e. counting all the 1's separated by '|'.

Comment: images ≠ text ;) I can't use images (please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: I apologize! @Mozay  I'll edit the question to include the text as well!

Comment: it doesn't, can you do `df.to_dict()` and provide the content?

Comment: @mozay Applied one more small edit recently. Should be the input df I used now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `stack` your dataframe and use `extractall` with your pattern:

```
(df.stack().str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
   #.astype(int)  # conversion to int is only required for other operations, like sum
   .groupby(level=[0,1]).count().unstack())
```

output:

```
   CF1  CF2
0    3    2
1    3    5
```

*NB. I am **counting** the numbers here (any number so "42" or "123" in "test123" would be counted as well), if you want to restrict to 1s only you can adapt the regex, and if you want you can also perform other operations like summing instead of counting*